# Windows Command - Delayed Expansion Syntax to Echo The VALUE of a Variable That Contains Another Number Variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-command-prompt, batch, command

I am trying to `echo` the VALUE of a variable whose name contains another variable (`$project!$project_number!_control`) while using delayed expansion. I can't figure out the syntax to do this.  Here's the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set $loop_counter=
for %%g in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) do (
    set /a $loop_counter+=1
    if !$loop_counter! gtr 4 (
        echo.
        rem echo $loop_counter = !$loop_counter!
        set /a $project_number=!$loop_counter!-4
        echo $project_number = !$project_number!
        set $project!$project_number!_control=Project Description # !$loop_counter!
        echo $project!$project_number!_control = !$project!$project_number!_control!
    )
)
echo.
pause
echo.
set
echo.
pause
```

The line of code I'm having the problem with is the last line in the `for` loop:

```
echo $project!$project_number!_control = !$project!$project_number!_control!
```

Specifically, it's the code to the right of the equal sign that echoes the VALUE of the `$project!$project_number!_control` variable that I'm having trouble with.  The `set` command (that is run after the `pause` command in the code above) clearly shows that the values "Project Description #5," "Project Description #6," "Project Description #7," and "Project Description #8" were assigned correctly to the corresponding project1_control, project2_control, project3_control, and project4_control, variables.

Can someone please tell me what syntax to use to display the VALUE of the `$project!$project_number!_control` variable?

Thanks In Advance For The Help!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is that the `$project!$project_number!_control` variable must undergo double expansion in order to return its value.  Exclamation marks cannot be used more than once with a variable when delayed expansion is enabled as I had done in my original code, below:

```
!$project!$project_number!_control!
```

Instead or the exclamation marks placed at the beginning and end of the variable as shown above, double percent signs (%%) should be placed at the beginning and end of the variable as follows:

```
%%$project!$project_number!_control%%
```

When delayed expansion takes place this statement will expand to:

```
%$project!$project_number!_control%
```

As can be seen in the expanded variable code above, the VALUE of the variable is still not returned.  To do that a SECOND expansion must take place.  To execute a second variable expansion, the `call` statement is placed in front of the `echo` statement at the beginning of the last line of code in the `for` loop.  The corrected last line of code in the `for` loop is:

```
call echo $project!$project_number!_control = %%$project!$project_number!_control%%
```

When the code executes with the corrected line of code everything works as expected.  The entire corrected code listing is now:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set $loop_counter=
for %%g in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) do (
    set /a $loop_counter+=1
    if !$loop_counter! gtr 4 (
        echo.
        rem echo $loop_counter = !$loop_counter!
        set /a $project_number=!$loop_counter!-4
        echo $project_number = !$project_number!
        set $project!$project_number!_control=Project Description # !$loop_counter!
        call echo $project!$project_number!_control = %%$project!$project_number!_control%%
    )
)
echo.
pause
echo.
set
echo.
pause
```

I hope this helps someone who has been struggling with using WIndows Command numbered variables.  **Remember, the `call` statement is the key to executing a second expansion when delayed expansion is enabled.**